# copy files from one linux VM instance to other in the same project on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to google cloud. I have seen the similar question but I couldn't understand the answer. It will be great if someone could give easy instruction to tackle this problem.
I have two linux VM instances under same project on google cloud. I want to copy files from one VM to other VM.

I tried copy-files command. It threw error "deprecated, use scp instead"
I tried "gcloud compute scp  user@vm2_instance_name:vm2_instance_file_path"

other answers say use "service account". I read about them and created one and created key as well in .json format but not sure what to do after that. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took time to answer my question.     I was getting error    ------*"ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed: - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."*------ Then I found the answer. [ https://acloud.guru/forums/gcp-certified-associate-cloud-engineer/discussion/-Lh3ET0aNrv3FwNbNvh6/Insufficient%20Permission:%20Request%20had%20insufficient%20authentication%20scopes.]. Thanks @marian.vladoi

Answer (score 1):

If you are in one instance, don't worry about Google Cloud. Simply perform a `scp` to copy file from VM to another one.

If you don't have customize users on the VM, you can omit it

`scp <my local file path> <vm name>:<destination path>`

About service account, if your VM are in Google Cloud, they have the compute engine service account by default `<projectNumber>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

You can customize this service account if you want. This service account is mandatory to identify the VM which perform API call or `gcloud` command

Answer (score 0):

[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) addresses this. Personally, I have always preferred using [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) as it provides both a simplistic way of performing transfers while not necessarily taking away any of the complexities and features that other transferring options provide.

In any case, in the documentation provided you will most likely find the method that are more in-line with what you want.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained with a link to documentation being added value. Links break and get removed; documentation changes. The Stackoverflow search engine cannot index details that are not there. In this example the OP said he tried `gcloud compute scp` and it did not work, so you refer him without a better solution to the same command.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the correction, will keep it in mind moving forward. Regarding my suggestion, I was under the assumption that it was the "copy-file" command that failed and not the `gcloud compute scp` although it may be a misunderstanding on my side.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
1. gcloud compute instances list 
   NAME            ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  
   INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
   instance-1      us-central1-a   n2-standard-8               
   10.128.0.60    34.66.177.187   RUNNING
   instance-2      us-central1-a   n1-standard-1               
   10.128.15.192  34.69.216.153   STAGING

2. gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a 

3. user@instance-1:~$ ls
   myfile

4. usernstance-1:~$ gcloud compute scp myfile user@instance-2:myfile

5. gcloud compute ssh instance-2 --zone=us-central1-a 

6. user@instance-2:~$ ls
   myfile
```